# Maven-Plugin for checking API-Compliance with Android

Tags: java, android, maven

I'm looking for a Maven-Plugin that can check Jar/Class-Files for compliance with a specified API Level of Android. E.g. can all Classes and Methods be resolved in the Android API..
Does someone know about such a plugin? The DX tool doesn't seem to provide such functionality or am I missing something?

**Use case:**
I wrote some Jar-Files which should be used in Desktop-Java-Applications as well in Android-Apps. Now I want to make sure that these Jar-Files are compliant to the Android API of a certain level.

My current workaround would be to run my Unit-Tests in an Android-Emulator.

Comment: I think this is a good question for SO. But don't be too disappointed when its deleted by some moderator because its against the guidelines of SO. I do not know of such a tool.

Comment: Sounds like a reasonable question to me.  Don't see why it would be deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there was no such tool available I wrote it myself.
http://code.google.com/p/compliancechecker/

It's a plugin for the maven build system which supports validating Java SE 1.4, 1.5, 1.6 and 1.7 code against a certain android api level.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [animal-sniffer-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/animal-sniffer/animal-sniffer-maven-plugin/) with [android-api-level signatures](https://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22net.sf.androidscents.signature%22).

This will looks like :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>animal-sniffer-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.16</version>
    <configuration>
        <signature>
            <groupId>net.sf.androidscents.signature</groupId>
            <artifactId>android-api-level-19</artifactId>
            <version>4.4_r1</version>
        </signature>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

See [animal-sniffer-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/animal-sniffer/animal-sniffer-maven-plugin/usage.html) for more details.

More resources about android level API :

- [android version history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history),
- [usage statistics](https://www.appbrain.com/stats/top-android-sdk-versions).