# Checking a JAR for android compatibility in maven

Tags: java, android, maven

Some of our jar libraries should run on android, as well as normal JDKs. The jar is build by maven. Specifically I want to know:

- Is it possible to build against another runtime library or to check the API compatibility?
- Is there some maven plugin that runs the JUnit tests on an android platform?
- What other verification steps should be taken to ensure that your library project will run on android?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/11048805/502399