# Which Java version should I use to create a library usable with Android

Tags: java, android, java-8, dependencies, java-11

I'm maintainer of an Open Source Java library.

I have no experience at all in Android development but **I would like that my library could be used in an Android app as dependency.** (at least I would avoid the main blocker issue)

It's not crystal clear to me but I understand there is several kind of Java Compatibility with Android :

1. API level
2. byte code compatibility
3. source code compatibility.

(Please to not hesitate to better explain this ☝ or correct me if I'm wrong)

I guess in my case I'm mainly concerned by the 2 first points.

Currently :

- we check API level with [animal-sniffer-maven-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49153640/5088764). (api-level-19)
- our releases are compiled against java7 with a openjdk7.

But I would like to upgrade to a more recent version of Java. (probably java8, but maybe java11)

**Can I use those jdk versions (openjdk8, openjdk11) to compile a library which could be used in android project ?**

My current research about this, but still not clear to me :

- https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support
- https://jakewharton.com/androids-java-9-10-11-and-12-support/
- https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin?utm_source=android-studio-2020-3-1&utm_medium=studio-assistant-stable#java-11

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: There is a difference between Java language features and Java APIs available. For example, your third link says that you can use Java 11 language features. That doesn't mean that Java 11 APIs are available (in fact, these are currently in the making and will probably be available in Android 13). Your best bet is to use Java 8 and you will mostly be compatible with API level 24. You can go below that and still compile with Java 8 but then you have to check if the Java 8 API you use is actually available. For example, `CompletableFuture` is a Java 8 API that wasn't available until API level 24.

Comment: @StefanZobel thx for this useful answer. I understand that "compiling with Java 8" + "limiting API usage with animal-sniffer-maven-plugin" should be good enough.